# PHP function to use password_hash, hash or MD5 depending on availability

Tags: php, hash

I'm creating a script and would ideally like to convert user password into a hash using password_hash function, however I want to make the hashing dynamic to make sure password_hash function actually exists, so i've written the following function to return a hash depending on what function is available.

```
function generateHash($hashpwd){
    if (function_exists('password_hash')) {
        return password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    } elseif (function_exists('hash')) {
        return hash('sha512', $hashpwd);
    } else {
        return md5($hashpwd);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this method or will it work? also I am creating the hash using password_hash in the following way:

```
password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

But most places i've seen example syntax in the following format:

```
password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

Difference being the \n is the \n needed and what is it for?

Comment: Did  you try it?

Comment: Just as a word of warning, what would happen in your case when the PHP executable that calls the script changes? As in, an upgrade to PHP past 5.5 makes `password_hash` available. What would happen with the hash if it had previously been hashed with sha512?

Comment: *"But most places i've seen example syntax in the following format:

password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";"* - You should read [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) first.

Comment: @Fred-ii-yes i tried it and seems to work.

Comment: This is a bad idea; you won't know how your password has been hashed so you won't be able to check it. Just use a single function and specify that your PHP version includes it.

Comment: password_hash was introduced in PHP 5.5.0 which has gone past End of Life so doesn't even get security updates now. Is it really worth your time writing code for people who leave themselves unpatched?

Comment: Ok, well there's something you need to know about that and I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471880/php-function-to-use-password-hash-hash-or-md5-depending-on-availability#comment79898887_46471880) just above about it.

Comment: @Simon It's pretty simple to inspect the resulting hash format and thereby detect what algorithm was used. If you want to be doubly sure you can save a version flag in a separate column in your database.

Comment: Thanks guys, so I will scrap the idea and just stick to using hash_password  seeing as it seem's that is the safe option

Comment: @Ahmed Please note that if a/your server doesn't support the `password_hash()` function, you can use the password compatibility pack, as per [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#110872) leading to https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every version of PHP that lacks `password_hash` (below 5.5) is now [end-of-lifed](http://php.net/eol.php) and insecure as a result. It is a) not worth accounting for these now dangerously-insecure versions of PHP, and b) not worth the security hit to your users caused by downgrading to MD5 as the hashing algorithm.

> But most places i've seen example syntax in the following format:
>
> ```
> password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
> ```

I've never, ever seen this done. `\n` is a new line. Saving that into your database alongside the hash will cause problems - it'd only be worth doing if you were outputting the hash somewhere for debugging/viewing.

Comment: so it's best to avoid the \n ?

Comment: @Ahmed Not just "best", it's absolutely silly to include the `\n`.

Comment: Thanks, so password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); is that the correct syntax

Comment: Just for context, @ceejayoz, that newline is shown in the [PHP documentation examples for password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). You're absolutely correct though; including the newline character is asinine

Comment: @ChrisForrence Holy crap, why would they *do* that?

Comment: @ceejayoz why a bug report? Jay Blanchard already posted a user contributed note about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017 and I think he even sent them a message about it. I've often questioned the fact why PHP.net even made a mention/included that `\n` in there in the first place *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- As the need for the note and this question indicates, it's potentially confusing, and the newline is not at all necessary to demonstrate the functionality. Removing it would improve the documentation, and there's a "documentation problem" category for PHP bug reports. A bug report may get them to edit the example.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah I know. I've been in conversation with a few members here about it before. I'm really hoping that they'll (php.net) listen this time and modify the documentation about it as some type of warning. Often times, people don't go over the entire page / manual for it (and read the contributed notes) and figure they can just add a variable to it. Well.... little do they know that that will fail them, over so *silently*. Edit: good move on the bug report :-)

Comment: @ceejayoz You stated though: *"Every version of PHP that lacks password_hash (below 5.5) is now end-of-lifed and insecure as a result."* - There is the compatibility pack though https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat as per [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#110872) supplied (the compatibility pack that is) by another member here on Stack, [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell).

Comment: Sure, but if you're needing the compatibility pack, you're using an out-of-date, dangerous PHP version. I don't recommend it anymore for that reason.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is sadly ridiculous. The description of the return value literally reads as "Returns the hashed password, or FALSE on failure". People that fail to read that, and understand that the newline is something else, should not be trusted with handling login systems anyway. Sadly, it seems otherwise they will just fallback on insecure basic hashing. +1 on the bug report I guess, but I hate this.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you for the bug report.  The documentation changes will be reflected on php.net in the next few hours.  The PHP project prides itself on its documentation, and little "issues" like this are easy to address and if it helpers future readers to understand the examples better then that is great.

Comment: @salathe Lovely, I appreciate it. The PHP.net docs have always been a bright spot in the community and my compliments to the entire team for that.

Comment: @ceejayoz It looks like the bug report changed things and I've made an edit to my answer in regards to this, under **Edit**. Thought you might like to know.

Comment: @salathe I'm glad to see that the documentation was modified, but why was [Jay Blanchard's contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) removed from the manual? That and/or stating something about its past usage. This could have adverse effects in regards to the many questions/answers I've seen here on Stack, something that I stated in an edit under my answer, if you'd like to have a look at it. I hope we're not to find those and having to edit them all.

Comment: The now-deleted note started with: *"Be care when using the example from the documentation which concatenates a newline character <code>\n</code> to the end of the hash …"*. The comment no longer holds true (there is no such example), the warning to readers is no-longer necessary, and the documentation is better for it; so I deleted the note.

Answer (score 5):

1. A single unsalted SHA512 is a bad fallback for `password_hash`. At the very least you need to use a different algorithm here **including a salt**. Preferably use [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) with a decent hash algorithm, which is what `password_hash` wraps anyway.
2. There's a [`password_hash` backport](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) available for PHP **5.3.7+**, depending on your OS even some older versions. You shouldn't realistically need to support anything older than that. You need to draw the line in the sand somewhere. Most new projects require at least 5.6+. If you need to support anything older, use a trusted library like [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), which is backwards compatible until PHP 3.
3. `password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";` is just for debugging output, the trailing newline is ***not*** part of the password hash.

Comment: I especially like your point #3 about *"is just for debugging output"*.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> Is there anything wrong with this method or will it work? also I am creating the hash using password_hash in the following way:

```
password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

> But most places i've seen example syntax in the following format:

```
password_hash($hashpwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

> Difference being the \n is the \n needed and what is it for?

There is a difference between both, a **big** one.

The second one will embed a hidden line break character that will make  your password verification fail silently.

As per [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) about the use of `password_hash()` supplied by [Jay Blanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard), a member here on Stack Overflow.

> Be care when using the example from the documentation which concatenates a newline character `\n` to the end of the hash, i.e.:
>
> `echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";`
>
> People are storing the hash with the concatenated newline and consequently `password_verify()` will fail.

---

**Edit:**

September 29th, 2017.

**Special note:**

I revisited the manual on [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) today and noticed that they removed the user contributed note http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017 (supplied by Jay Blanchard) where the documentation was modified to remove the `\n` reference, where it now reads as:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

which removed the `."\n"` from it.

This now has a bearing on the question asked and answers given.

I believe this had something to do with a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75276) filed yesterday, as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471880/php-function-to-use-password-hash-hash-or-md5-depending-on-availability/46471958#comment79899287_46471947) in another answer inside this same question.

I also have to note that this modification (of the manual's syntax) could have adverse effects on previously posted answers stating that the url is no longer valid.

Personally, I feel they should have kept that note in there and/or stated something about its previous usage.